# What is this property of Borel measures called?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, definition

Consider a Borel measure (on a metric space) that is nonzero on all uncountable Borel subsets of the space, and zero on all countable Borel subsets of the space.

Is there a specific name for this property of the measure? I would like to give it a name in a text I'm writing, but that would of course be unnecessary if it already has one.

Comment: I am tempted to think that the only measure satisfying this property for any metric space is the measure that is $0$ on countable sets and $\infty$ on uncountable sets. Though I don't know how to prove this, I don't have any counterexamples yet. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @KeeferRowan I have a "possible" example, though, I still have to prove that it is indeed nonzero on all uncountable Borel subsets (but in fact proving this isn't that important).  All I really need is an easy way to refer to this property.  The possible example involves a self-affine measure on a special case of a self-affine set and the maximal Hausdorff dimension of this measure. It would be lengthy to define it, though, as it requires some background knowledge.

Comment: I don't know enough theory to even understand that example, but my intuition suggests that if we have a finite measure uncountable set, we should be able to take a nested sequence of uncountable sets with uncountable intersection that have measure converging to $0$.  E.g. this happens in $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure for the Cantor set. I have no idea how to show (if) this happens in general (even over $\mathbb R$, but it is an interesting question, though it doesn't seem to be the one you're interested in.

Comment: If $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x$ (this is sometimes called a non-atomic measure) then all countable subsets have measure $0$. But most likely there will be uncountable Borel sets of measure $0$ too, unless you use a two-valued measure with values $0$ and $+\infty$ e.g., which is quite trivial. You probably cannot come up with such an example, so why bother naming it?

Comment: In most typical metric spaces, and specifically in complete metric spaces, each uncountable Borel set contains uncountably many disjoint uncountable Borel sets, basically by Keefer's argument below.  This would force every uncountable Borel set to have measure infinity and make everything trivial.  Do you actually have an example of a metric space where this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

We can show that the only measure satisfying this property on a Polish space (i.e. a separable topological space that admits a complete metric) is the trivial one (i.e. $0$ on countable sets and $\infty$ on uncountable ones).

Define a Borel isomoprhism to be a measurable bijection with a measurable inverse.

Theorem 8.3.6 of Donald L. Cohn's *Measure Theory* states that any two uncountable subsets of a Polish space are Borel isomorphic.

It is also a standard result that any two Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic. Since Borel isomorphic measurable spaces admit the same collection of measures, we can WLOG consider putting a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology. So suppose we have a Borel measure satisfying your property on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is uncountable, every uncountable Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Borel isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as the uncountable disjoint union of uncountable Borel sets (consider translates of the $x$-axis), thus any uncountable Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as the uncountable disjoint union of uncountable Borel sets. Thus every uncountable Borel set has infinite measure. Thus the measure is the trivial one.