# Are Borel subsets of Polish spaces Polish?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Are Borel subsets of Polish spaces Polish? I would imagine not, since I would think that would be noted in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) on them, and it isn't.

This question arises in connection to trying to show that measures of the sort asked about in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814544/what-is-this-property-of-borel-measures-called) don't exist besides the trivial one.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the linked question?

Comment: @NateEldredge Turns out I didn't need. If you look at my answer you'll see that I show that no non-trivial such measure can exist on Polish spaces. I thought I needed Borel subsets of Polish spaces to be Polish, but it suffices that they are Lusin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple counterexample is the set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  It has no isolated points, therefore every point of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a nowhere dense subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.  But $\mathbb{Q}$ is the countable union of such points, which if it were Polish would contradict the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Why not consider the metric $d(x,y) = 1_{\{x\neq y\}}$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$. This seems to be a complete and separable metric space.  Moreover the sigma algebra is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, as it would be under the usual metric on $\mathbb{Q}$.  Perhaps there is some subtle issue about being allowed to change the metric while fixing some assumed "topology of open sets."

Comment: @Michael: When we speak of topological properties of a subset of a topological space, by default we endow it with the subspace (aka relative) topology.  So I interpret the question as whether a Borel subset $A$ of a Polish space $X$ is necessarily Polish with respect to the subspace topology inherited from $X$, and the answer is no.

Comment: @Michael: If you want to let the topology / metric be changed arbitrarily, then the answer is a trivial yes.  Every Borel subset of a Polish space either is countable, in which case the discrete metric works, or has the same cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ as $\mathbb{R}$ (or whatever is your favorite uncountable Polish space), in which case identify it with $\mathbb{R}$ and use the usual metric.  Now, I think if you only allow a metric which is stronger or weaker, there are some interesting theorems, whose statements I don't currently recall.

Comment: Thanks.  It is not just that it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so measurability and sigma algebra properties are preserved. But it seems here, instead of just caring about a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{F})$, we also care about what constitutes an "open set" (even if two different collections of open sets on $X$ generate the same sigma algebra on $X$).

Comment: @Michael: That's right.  And the point is that, between my topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ (the subspace topology, i.e. the "usual" topology) and yours (the discrete topology), the open sets are totally different.  So by switching the metric / topology, one would essentially ignore all the meaningful structure.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Only $G_\delta$ subsets of Polish spaces are Polish (equipped with the subspace topology). Nevertheless, if you are given a Polish space $X$ and its Borel subset $B$ (not necessarily $G_\delta$) then you can find a Polish topology on $X$ giving the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra as the original topology on $X$, in which $B$ is clopen (hence Polish if considered with topology induced by the new topology on $X$).

Comment: Why does your answer not contradict the Nate Eldredge answer?

Comment: @Michael: My answer says that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not Polish with respect to the subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  This answer asserts that there is a *different* topology $\tau'$ on $\mathbb{R}$, for which the subspace topology inherited by $\mathbb{Q}$ is Polish, and the other mentioned conditions hold.  You might like to try to work out what that topology could be.

Comment: @NateEldredge : I suppose that if we assume $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is Polish with some metric $d(x,y)$ (while it is not easy to see this can be made complete, let's use the $G_{\delta}$ fact for this), then separate out the rationals in some metric on $\mathbb{R}$ like $d'(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$, $d'(x,y)=1$ if either $x$ or $y$ is rational (but $x\neq y$), $d'(x,y)=\max[d(x,y), 1]$ else.

Answer (score 3):

No. A subset of Polish space is Polish in the relative topology if and only if it is $G_\delta$. The inverse implication is attributed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space#Properties) to Alexandroff. For a proof, check Kechris' book, Theorem 3.11 in section 3.C.

In an uncountable Polish space without isolated points, any countable dense set can't be Polish, by the Baire Category Theorem (and the previous theorem): if it were $G_\delta$, it is the intersection of a countable family of dense open sets, and hence it can't be (included) in the countable union of closed sets with empty interior.

Comment: Reference? Also if you can trace the argument that uses the Baire Category Theorem, that'd be nice.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding references right now, and that argument.

Comment: Other results: Let $X$ be a non-empty completely-metrizable space with no isolated points. By a construction analogous to the construction of the Cantor set $C,$ the space $X$ has a subspace $Y$ where $Y$ is homeomorphic to $C.$ Hence $|X|\ge |C|=2^{\aleph_0}.$ And if $X'$ is a dense and completely-metrizable subspace of $X $ then $X'$ is also non-empty with no isolated points, so $|X'|\ge |C|.$